# RabbitMQ HA cluster graceful shutdown of a master node when using 'when-synced' policy

Tags: rabbitmq, high-availability

Suppose I use ‘when-synced’ policy for both ha-promote-on-failure, ha-promote-on-shutdown on a HA cluster.

If so, ‘mirror to master promotion' will never be occurred and the master queue is blocked if there are no synchronized mirrors on controlled master shutdown.

That's what the documentation says.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html#cluster-shutdown

> By default, RabbitMQ will refuse to promote an unsynchronised mirror
>   on controlled master shutdown (i.e. explicit stop of the RabbitMQ
>   service or shutdown of the OS) in order to avoid message loss; instead
>   the entire queue will shut down as if the unsynchronised mirrors were
>   not there.

If using 'when-synced' policy and if no mirrors were synchronized at the time of shutting down the master, according to the documentation, master doesn’t seem to shutdown gracefully.

For me it seems like there are only two options.

1. Waiting for a master to be restored (regardless of how long it takes) if I use ‘when-synced’.
2. Abandoning all the messages that are not yet synchronized to mirrors (exist only in the master) for availability if I use ‘always’.

Really?
**There’s no option like “Blocking queues until one of the mirrors is fully synced, and then promote the synced mirror to the new master”?**

Comment: It's 2023 and there is still no "sync then shutdown" option (to my knowledge and research).